# Уменьшение время подгрузки данных в Chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, chosen

Что имею: n-ное количество переменных (500-2000), которые достаю из базы и передаю в нужный мне `, созданного при помощи плагина **[Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)**:

```
    function get_ims() {
    var select = document.getElementById('choosen')
    axios.get('functions.php?query=' + 'ims')
        .then(function (response) {
            var data = response.data;
            for (s in data) {
                $(select).append("<option value='" + data[s] + "'>" + data[s] + "</option>");
                $(select).trigger("chosen:updated");
            }
        });
}
```

Из-за такого большого количества данных загрузка самой страницы происходит ужасно медленно - в Хроме около 30секунд, против к примеру секунды, когда переменных было около 50. 
Есть ли какие варианты способные уменьшить время обработки?

Comment: Вы уверенны в том, что страница долго грузится из-за большого времени обработки переменных, а не из-за долгого времени ожидания ответа от сервера и скачивания данных?

Comment: @MishaSaidov, да, так как в ранней версии проекта забирал от базы переменный в количестве 7-8тысяч и производил с ними расчёты на стороне клиента (по дурости), и то, он делал это гораздо быстрее

Comment: Все эти 30 секунд вы видите зависшую (из-за цикла) и ни на что не реагирующую страницу?

Comment: Могу посоветовать использовать `document.createElement("option")` вместо `$(select).append("<option ...`, что будет гораздо быстрее или вообще не использовать jq, если вам важна производительность ибо большинство jq функций - синтаксический сахар и обертки над нативными функциями js, и их использование приведет к увеличению времени выполнения всего цикла.

Comment: @MishaSaidov, ну почти. Вижу прогрузившийся каркас, но сделать никаких действий с элементами(кнопками, вкладками) не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Вот наглядное сравнение производительности `$.append()` и `appendChild()`. 500 итераций. Как видите на ванильном js выполняется в 50-80 раз быстрее.

```js
console.time("jq append");
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  $("body").append("<div></div>");
}
console.timeEnd("jq append");

document.body.innerHTML = "";

console.time("pure js appendChild");
for (let i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
  let div = document.createElement("div");
  document.body.appendChild(div);
}
console.timeEnd("pure js appendChild");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, что у вас загрузка страницы происходит медленно, из-за того что вы сильно нагружаете `DOM-дерево` добавляя каждый `option` по одному в `select`, также после добавления каждого узла вы вызываете `$(select).trigger("chosen:updated");`.

Предлагаю добавлять `options` все сразу и один раз вызывать `trigger`;

```js
function get_ims() {
  var select = $('#choosen');
  axios.get('functions.php?query=ims')
    .then(function(response) {
      var data = response.data,
        options = [];
      for (var s in data) {
        options.push('<option value="' + data[s] + '">' + data[s] + '</option>');
      }
      $(select).append(options).trigger("chosen:updated");;
    });
}
```